# Android Double Press Homebutton

Tags: android, launch, android-homebutton

I am a android app developer trying to launch my app when the user double presses the home button. So I've encountered an app called Home2Shortcut which exactly does this when the settings are set well. It seems that what it is doing is,

homebutton pressed once --> opens Home2shortcut --> opens home view (fast enough it seems as if it is opening homeview directly)
homebutton pressed once --> opens Home2shortcut --> pressed again --> my app.

However, I would like to achieve this in my app without getting help from another app. Im thinking similar way like

setting my app as default for home screen, 
home button pressed --> my app --> opens home view
pressed again --> comes back to my app.

I really want to know how Home2shortcut did it programatically, and if there is any suggestion I would be more than glad to know about it

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share some screen shots for better understanding.